# SwiftUI hide hamburger icon in list while in EditMode

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Pretty self explanatory question, I'm looking for a way to hide the hamburger menu (and not .moveDisabled(true), I still want .onMove to work because I need the drag-and-drop functionality) when EditMode is active in SwiftUI.

The situation, I have a List with a bunch of elements that need to be able to move around, but the hamburger/3-lines icon on the right hand side is super ugly and disrupts the flow of my app. If there is an ugly solution like setting the margin to the right super high or something like that I'm more than willing to do that; I just need a way to preserve the drag-and-drop functionality without having the icon visible.

my code just looks like this

```
List {
     ForEach(items) { item in 
          item.contextMenu {
               //...
          }
     }.onMove(perform: onMove)
}.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
```

there's obviously other stuff in the code but its not relevant, just need to know how to hide the hamburger icon.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can probably do this with a LazyVGrid instead of a List.  Then for each view representing a cell, add .onDrag and .onDrop. Your solution is then fully customizable.
Your model needs to handle returning an appropriate NSItemProvider in onDrag, and it needs to provide a DropDelegate object in onDrop.

I would google swift onDrop and you will find many discussions.